# Fetch JMS configurations and property values for each individual servers in WAS using wsadmin script

Tags: jms, jython, wsadmin, ibm-was, jacl

I need to fetch JMS configurations and property values for each individual servers of WAS using wsadmin script. Is there any IBM standard jython or jacl script is there to fetch these values ? If not, can somebody guide me how to procceed.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific what configuration settings you want to set.

Comment: I don't want to set any configuration, I want to fetch the exsiting configuration details of JMS providers of IBM WAS like General properties, Class path , Class path , External initial context factory ,External provider URL.......

Answer (score 0):

You can export your server configuration via wsadmin command (this will export all server configuration):

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName ConfigProperties_server1.props -configData Server=server1]')
```

To extract properties related to MQ JMS resources you could provide subtype in the script:

```
AdminTask.extractConfigProperties('[-propertiesFileName mq.props -configData Server=server1 -filterMechanism SELECTED_SUBTYPES -selectedSubTypes [MQConnectionFactory MQQueue]]')
```

You could modify required properties and then import them to different server/environment.
See more details about different types and usage here [Extracting properties files using wsadmin scripting](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-base-dist&topic=txml_7extractprops).

Answer (score 0):

AdminTask and AdminConfig are good tools for this.

You can use the jython line "print AdminTask.help('-commands')" to print all the commands that your configuration supports.

As for AdminConfig you will need a bit of knowledge on how was xml configurations are stored.

See for more info: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en